# 3D Spherical Polar Plot, with a 4th Dimension Mapped to Another Variable

Tags: r, polar-coordinates, geometry-surface, 4d, spherical-coordinate

First, I have found a few threads on this sort of theme, but none of them seem to quite do what I want, or at least I am having a real brain fart in trying to work it out, so I appreciate others input.

I have 4 variables that make up a polar plot, R, theta, phi and A, where A represents a measurement.

```
library(data.table)
library(viridis)
library(plot3D)
library(plotly)

df<-data.table(theta = seq(0,2*pi, length.out = 100))
df<-df[,.(phi= seq(0,pi/2, length.out = 100)),.(theta)]
df[, A:=rnorm(10000)]
#I've included r set to one just for the example's sake
df[, r:=1]
```

It is easy enough to plot this sort of data on a polar co-ord axis in 2d (for a given phi) and have the value A represented by the radius, for example using plotly:

```
p <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  mode = 'lines',
  r = df[theta == 0]$A,
  theta = (df[phi == 0]$theta)*(180/pi),
)
p
```

which gives:

[image: Plotly Polar Plot]

However, this measurement is essentially the strength of a reflection at a set radius over a grid of spherical coordinates, and it would be really nice to represent it that way. In other words, have my sphere with a fixed radius and an A value for each coordinate, and plot the sphere surface with a colour that corresponds to the A value. The closest I have come is this, using 'scatter3d' from the plot3D package:

```
#convert to cartesian

df[,x:=r*cos(theta)*sin(phi)]
df[,y:=r*sin(theta)*sin(phi)]
df[,z:=r*cos(phi)]

#plot

scatter3D(x = df$x, 
          y = df$y, 
          z = df$z, 
          zlim = c(-1,1),
          ylim = c(-1,1),
          xlim = c(-1,1),
          pch =18,
          bty = 'b2',
          colvar = df$A,
          col=inferno(200))
```

which produces:
[image: hemisphere plot]

Now this is in the right direction, but I'd love to be able to:
A) have this as a coloured surface rather than a series of points,
B) be able to spin it around etc. like you can with the rgl package,
c) have a labelled polar axis rather than the cartesian box, though this one I think is totally out of scope.

The other packages I have unsuccesfully tried, tend to require some casting of the polar coordinates into regularly spaced matrices of cartesian coords, and then don't always allow you to map a colour as well (or at least I cant figure out how to get the mapping of A onto a matrix of x, y and z).

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried this with `rgl` yet?

Comment: I have tried, the only one I am getting anywhere with is plot3d:

`plot3d(df$x,
       df$y,
       df$z)
`

But I cannot then get the colours to map. Surf3d seems to require matricies that I  struggle to get my head around!